# When does 感謝 happen in 分かるように分かりやすく説明してあげるから感謝しなさいよね！

Tags: grammar

Does 感謝 happen before 説明 or after? It's possible to write "分かるように分かりやすく説明してあげるから後で感謝しなさいよね！" so I feel it might be ambiguous, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

To be fair, the English would be just as ambiguous: "I'm gonna say it nice and simple so even you can understand, so thank me [feel thankful], will ya?"

Comment: For me, both in English and Jp, thanking seems to be requested NOW, even before the explanation starts.

Answer (score 0):

感謝 happen after 説明. "後で感謝しなさいよね" this sentence is meant the feelings of the speaker.

When's another writing in Japanese: "あなたが理解できるように私が分かりやすく説明をします。私の説明が終了したら、私に感謝して下さい。". In English: "I will explain as you can understand that. After I have finished the easy-to-understand explanation, I want you to show the gratitude."

"分かるように分かりやすく説明してあげるから後で感謝しなさいよね！"
This sentence is used between people of relatives or close relationship if help the people in trouble with minor problems.
So part of the statement is omitted.